# Getting parts of large csv. saved as Excel to open directly in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, csv

My issue has been to get a csv-file saved in Excel to actually open without any errors when I try to open it through vba. Every time ive tried I get all columns in to one single column. If I double click the file it opens as text in a excel-sheet with 96 columns. Excel sorts the values some how I don't understand.
So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with (with a lot of help I have to say), hopefully this can help others and it can be used in other settings as well. Ive added some helptext in there as well.

So the function and the sub ive added to a module:

```
'Note the input parameters use ByVal and ByRef.  ByVal means that I'm passing a variable by making a copy of it,
'       and whatever I do with it in this routine doesn't affect the variable in the parent calling routine.
'       ByRef means that the variable is that same variable that is being passed, not a copy of it, and so any
'       changes to that object will still exist when returning to execution of the parent routine.
'       As a rule, use ByVal unless you know that you want the parent routine to be aware of the changes to
'       the variable, or if you are passing an object that you want to really make changes to, such as a worksheet.

'Writing to a worksheet cell by cell is quite slow, so we are going to speed things up by allowing the parent routine
'       to specify which columns are wanted, using the "columnsWanted" input parameter

Public Sub import_csv_using_text_file_read_method(ByVal filePathName As String, _
                                              ByRef outputSheet As Worksheet, _
                                     Optional ByVal columnsWanted As String = "")
'clear output sheet, and select it
outputSheet.Cells.ClearContents
outputSheet.Select
'read file into an array of string type variables
Dim data() As String
data = readFileIntoStringArray(filePathName)
'now we are going to write this array to the spreadsheet
Dim outputRow As Long
outputRow = 0 '< this is the output row pointer, we will increment this as we go, so first increment will write to row 1
Dim i As Long '< array position pointer
Dim outputColumnIndex As Long '< output column
Dim cellData() As String, cellDataPos As Long 'we are going to "Split" the file line using semicolon, to give us an array of strings
Dim headers() As String 'keeping a copy of the column headers from the first row
'                                               ...for each output cell, and we will use cellDataPos as a pointer to read from this array
For i = 0 To UBound(data) '< "Ubound" gives us the maximum index of the array, remember we index from zero, so if Ubound(myArray)=9 then we have 10 items
    outputRow = outputRow + 1 '< incrementing the output row for every input file line
    outputColumnIndex = 0 '< reset output column index pointer
    Application.StatusBar = "Writing output: row " & Format(outputRow, "#,##0") & " (" & Format(i / UBound(data), "0.0 %") & ")" '< visual progress update
    'now let's use the clever "Split" function
    cellData = Split(data(i), ";")
    'take a copy of these for "headers" if this is the first row
    If i = 0 Then headers = cellData
    'now iterate the input columns
    For cellDataPos = 0 To UBound(cellData)
        'we only care about certain columns, if the header exists in "columnsWanted" (if this is not specified, then return all columns)
        If InStr(";" & LCase(columnsWanted) & ";", ";" & LCase(headers(cellDataPos)) & ";") > 0 Or columnsWanted = "" Then
            'so we want this one, increment the output column index pointer
            outputColumnIndex = outputColumnIndex + 1
            'we are only going to bother writing the value if it has some content, let's not fire blanks!
            If Len(Trim(cellData(cellDataPos))) > 0 Then
                'actually write it
                outputSheet.Cells(outputRow, outputColumnIndex).Value = Trim(cellData(cellDataPos))
            End If
            'note, I am using TRIM(variableName) to strip out any leading or trailing spaces from the data,
            '                 that we can see in the text file in notepad
        End If
    Next
    DoEvents '< a bit of grease
Next
'end
Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
-------------------------------------------

'*** routine to import the file into a string array ***
'
'           ...note the extra brackets at the end of this function type definition,  As String()
'           this means it will return an array of type string, not just a single string
Private Function readFileIntoStringArray(ByVal filePathName As String) As String()
'declare the output array
Dim outputArray() As String
'I'm not going to "Redim" the array to a specific size, as I will increase it every time I write a string to it
'This following variable "arrayPos" I will use as a pointer to the last item in the array.  On first use, this
'will increment to zero, ie. the first position in the array, for now I'm just getting it ready.
Dim arrayPos As Long
arrayPos = -1
'open the file, and read each line from it (easy code to lift from google)
Dim fileContentLine As String
Open filePathName For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, fileContentLine
    'write this file content line to the output array
    arrayPos = arrayPos + 1
    Application.StatusBar = "Reading file: line " & Format(arrayPos + 1, "#,##0") '< visual progress update
    If arrayPos = 0 Then
        ReDim outputArray(0) 'the first time we "dimension" (set the size of) an array, we cannot use "Preserve"
    Else
        ReDim Preserve outputArray(arrayPos) 'when increasing the size of an existing array, we use "Preserve" to keep existing contents, not wipe them
    End If
    outputArray(arrayPos) = fileContentLine
Loop
Close #1
'return the outputArray
readFileIntoStringArray = outputArray
'end
Application.StatusBar = ""
End Function
```

Then ive created a module with the next part and the reff cells where I add the path to the folder and the CSV File name.

```
Public Sub ImportCSV_buttonClick()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'assemble a file path name, that includes the folder and file name
Dim FPN As String
With Sheets(".")
    FPN = .Cells(2, 3).Value
    If Right(FPN, 1) <> "\" Then FPN = FPN & "\"
    FPN = FPN & .Cells(3, 3).Value
End With
'what columns do we want?
Dim columnsWeWant As String
columnsWeWant = "Art.nr form;name ;price;deliv;next deliv.;Status"
'import file using generic routine
csvImport.import_csv_using_text_file_read_method FPN, Sheets("output"), columnsWeWant
'End
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This forces the file in to the sheet where I have the code and the sheet "Output" with only the columns I need from the large csv.

**EDIT**
A csv has "," as seperator while this has ";" cause of regional settings. Still this can be used with changing that part.

Comment: CSV are Comma-Separated Value file. It is expected to have a comma as separator, not a semicolon. Excel sometime replace the comma with semicolons according to the regional settings when exporting to csv, but I think it should be noted in your answer that you are using a specific dsv file and not a real csv.

Comment: If your issue is with the semicolon, can you not use the `Workbooks.OpenText` method ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx)) and specify your delimiter?

Comment: @asongtoruin tried that, did not help much. that's why this "enormous" code